# FluentValidation when AbstractValidator is an array

Tags: c#, asp.net, fluentvalidation

Looking to run validation against the array itself as well as the items in the array. We cannot wrap the array in another class. Problem is I can't seem to get this to validate against the items in the array itself.

```
public class MyItemArrayValidator : AbstractValidator<MyItem[]>
{
    RuleFor(list => list)
        .Must(list => list.Length <= 25)
        .WithMessage("Too many items in array"));

    //Line that does not work below
    RuleFor(list => list).SetCollectionValidator(new MyItemValidator());
}

public class MyItemValidator : AbstractValidator<MyItem>
{
    ... validate MyItem stuff
}
```

**Update**
The error returned when calling the line...

```
RuleFor(list => list).SetCollectionValidator(new MyItemValidator());
```

is "Nested validators can only be used with Member Expressions."

I understand the error is because I'm working on the object and not a member, so maybe this approach is incorrect.

Comment: Did you mean .Must(list => list.Length > 25) ? (greater than instead of less  than )

Comment: @FeryalBadili no, the list cannot be more than 25, that RuleFor works as expected. The problem though is on the arrays items. I just wanted to demonstrate that I wanted to work on the array itself as well as its members.

Answer (score 2):

I found this in the documentation, using

> RuleForEach

> SetValidator

```
public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer> {
  public CustomerValidator() {
    RuleForEach(x => x.Orders).SetValidator(new OrderValidator());
  }
}

public class OrderValidator : AbstractValidator<Order> {
  public OrderValidator() {
    RuleFor(x => x.Total).GreaterThan(0);
  }
}
```

[FluentValidationDocumentation-link](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/collections.html)